# Removing the first NA in a path

Tags: r

I have created a path on R using many different variables. However some of the variables have NA, and has been added to the paths.

```
1 > 2 > NA > NA > 0
1 > 3 > 2 > NA > 0
1 > NA > NA > NA > 0
1 > 3 > 4 > NA > 0
2 > 3 > 1 > NA > 0
6 > 2 > NA > NA > 1
```

I want to stop the path when the first NA occurs. I dont care about the other numbers after the NA value. I want the path to look like this.

```
1 > 2
1 > 3 > 2
1
1 > 3 > 4
2 > 3 > 1
6 > 2
```

I have tried to use strsplit, code below, but I am not sure how I could do this and get an error.

```
for(row in 1:nrow(data)){
data$path[row] = strsplit(channel$path[row], ">")[[1]][1]
}
```

Comment: How about: `sub(" > NA.*", "", channel$path)`

Comment: Thank you. I have been stuck on this for quite a while

Comment: I think that should be possible or you could try strsplit and split it at the "_". Have not tried that though

Answer (score 0):

After splitting by `" > "`, convert to `numeric` to change the character "NA" to `NA`, then, `paste` the elements until the first NA elements

```
sapply(strsplit(df1$v1, " > "), function(x) {
           x1 <- as.numeric(x)
           paste(x1[seq(which(is.na(x1))[1]-1)], collapse=" > ")})
#[1] "1 > 2"     "1 > 3 > 2" "1"         "1 > 3 > 4" "2 > 3 > 1" "6 > 2"
```